# How to get the photos related to a friend using facebook graph api?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook-graph-api

I have all the list of friends which I get using

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" andDelegate:self];.
```

Using this I get all the ids of my friends. I get all my photos too by using

```
 [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos" andDelegate:self];.
```

But what I should I use as the argument in requestWithGraphPath: if I want the photos related to any one of my friends?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple trick to fetch your friends photo.

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"FriendID/albums" andDelegate:self];`

e.g

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"123456789/albums" andDelegate:self];
```

which returns album id along with some information.

Comment: I tried this earlier too but the result is always 0. What to do?I have given permissions friends_photos and publish_stream.

Comment: Instead of Photos send as Albums that's it. Look For my updated code

Comment: thanks a lot. now i get the albumid and using it i can get the photos inside that album. But for getting all the photos I should send different requests with each albumids. So I guess there is no way to get all the photos at the same time.

Comment: ya you are right. Go a head. Accept the answer if it helped you in solving your issue.